# Make tomcat application stopped by default

Tags: java, tomcat

Using the Tomcat Web Application Manager, I can stop, start, reload & undeploy particular applications. Any applications that I stop in this way, automatically start again when Tomcat itself is restarted.

How can I configure a particular application to NOT start when Tomcat starts, and only start when I start it myself via Web Application Manager?

Comment: "Default stopped" and "default not deployed" are two different things. The two unchcked answers seem to answer in wrong place, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `deployOnStartup="false"` on your `<Host`> element in `conf/server.xml`. Note that this will cause the `manager` application to *also* not deploy on startup. You have a few options for that:

1. Configure the manager with a `<Context>` in `conf/server.xml`
2. Use a separate `<Host>` with `deployOnStartup="true"` and deploy the manager to that host instead

The [Automatic Deployment Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/automatic-deployment.html) is a pretty good resource to see what combinations of events and configurations will exhibit what behavior.

Comment: Any sample example for configuring manager <Context> with conf/server.xml

Comment: I could show you how to do it but (a) it's simple to figure out and (b) it's not recommended to put `<Context>` into `conf/server.xml`, so don't do it. If you don't want the server to start your application on startup, why is it there in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

There is `deployIgnore` attribute in `Host` element of server.xml.

It accepts regexp of context to NOT deploy.

Reference [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Common_Attributes):

> A regular expression defining paths to ignore when autoDeploy and
>   deployOnStartup are set. This allows you to keep your configuration in
>   a version control system, for example, and not deploy a .svn or CVS
>   folder that happens to be in the appBase.
>
> This regular expression is relative to appBase. It is also anchored,
>   meaning the match is performed against the entire file/directory name.
>   So, foo matches only a file or directory named foo but not foo.war,
>   foobar, or myfooapp. To match anything with "foo", you could use
>   .*foo.*.

Some more explanation [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment) :

> Any web application archive file within the Host's appBase directory
>   that has not already been deployed as a result of a context XML
>   descriptor, does not have a corresponding directory of the same name
>   (without the ".war" extension), and is not excluded by deployIgnore
>   will be deployed next. The context path used will be a slash character
>   ("/") followed by the web application archive name less the ".war"
>   extension. The one exception to this rule is that a web application
>   archive named "ROOT.war" will be deployed with a context path of /.
>   Multi-level contexts may be defined by using #, e.g. use a WAR named
>   foo#bar.war for a context path of /foo/bar.

**UPDATE**

To prove my answer I tried to answer [@rgh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1824572/rgh) comment bellow.

Just downloaded recent version of Tomcat8 (8.0.30).
It does ship (among others) with web application "examples".

Start **without** any modification (excerpt from catalina.out):

```
Deploying web application directory /home/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.30/webapps/examples 
Deployment of web application directory /home/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.30/webapps/examples has finished in 256 ms
```

Start with modified server.xml with snipped:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" deployIgnore="^examples$" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

Prevents application "examples" to be deployed.

So in your case, try this

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" deployIgnore="^welcome$" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work though if the directory structure is already set up in webapps does it?

For example, I have a webapps/welcome folder, but I don't want the welcome application, that ships with tomcat to automatically start whenever tomcat reboots. 

Modifying server.xml to include:

<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployIgnore="/welcome">

doesn't stop the welcome application from starting.

Comment: Well, thanks rkosegi, maybe it's different on tomcat 7, but for me that technique isn't working:
  


<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployIgnore="^welcome$">  


INFO: Deployment of web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\welcome.war has finished in 469 ms

Comment: @rgh : I tried just now with Tomcat 7.0.64 on Windows. It works as expected. Try this deployIgnore="^welcome.*"

Comment: Ah! That works! Problem now is that the welcome application doesn't show up in the manager application at all, so I can't start it when I need to.

Comment: Hi, I saw this question/answer about a year later.  Like in rgh's last comment (Feb 2, 2016), I could suppress my web app from being started automatically by tomcat (while other still start, including manager), but then my manager is now showing that web app.  Have you find a solution?

Comment: any solution to make the application visible in manager's list of webapps?